# Read params from JSON Chef

Tags: ruby, json, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to pass some values into chef recipe from the json file.
All I want is to set some values in my recipe from the remote file.

My json file `my_conf.json` looks like this:

```
{ 
  "something": {
    "listen_port": "81",
    "listen_path": "/myapp"
  },
  "users":{
     "user": "me"
  }
}
```

I run my chef-client with this json in params:

```
chef-client -z run.rb -j my_conf.json
```

In the recipe I tried:

```
@test = node[:something][:listen_port]
@test = node['something']['listen_port']
@test = node.default[:something][:listen_port]
```

But nothing works.
Any ideas?

Comment: What are you actually doing with the contents of `@test`? In the recipe code, this works perfectly `puts node['something']['listen_port']` (same for the version using symbols (`:something`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node['something']['listen_port']` is correct but `node[:something][:listen_port]` will work as well. More likely assigning to an instance variable (`@test =`) instead of a normal local variable (`test =`) is confusing things. Chef does a lot of magic with Ruby scoping internally.